# onClickListener conflict

Tags: android, android-viewpager, onclicklistener

[image]I'm using two libraries on the same view [NavigationTabBar](https://github.com/Devlight/NavigationTabBar?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=3382) &&  .. [SpaceNavigationView](https://github.com/armcha/Space-Navigation-View) and both of them are working fine when trying to run any of them separately .. but when adding both of them at the same time NavigationTabBar works fine while SpaceNavigationView onClickListener stop working.

- MainActivity :

  ```
  spaceNavigationView = (SpaceNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.space);
  navigationTabBar = (NavigationTabBar) findViewById(R.id.ntb_horizontal);
  final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.vp_horizontal_ntb);
  viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter() {
      @Override
      public int getCount() {
          return 4;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean isViewFromObject(final View view, final Object object) {
          return view.equals(object);
      }

      @Override
      public void destroyItem(final View container, final int position, final Object object) {
          ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
      }

      @Override
      public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
          if (position == 0) {
              final View view = LayoutInflater.from(
                      getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.final_circle_menu, null, false);
              container.addView(view);
              return view;
          } else {
              TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
              textView.setText("" + position);
              container.addView(textView);
              return textView;
          }
      }
  });

  final String[] colors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.default_preview);

  final ArrayList<NavigationTabBar.Model> models = new ArrayList<>();
  models.add(
          new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(
                  getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_about),
                  Color.parseColor(colors[0]))
                  .selectedIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_home))
                  .build()
  );
  models.add(
          new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(
                  getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_news_events),
                  Color.parseColor(colors[1]))                        .selectedIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_eighth))
                  .build()
  );
  models.add(
          new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(
                  getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_home),
                  Color.parseColor(colors[2]))
                  .selectedIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_news_events))
                  .build()
  );
  models.add(
          new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(
                  getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_servises),
                  Color.parseColor(colors[4]))
                  .selectedIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_news_events))
                  .build()
  );

  navigationTabBar.setModels(models);
  navigationTabBar.setViewPager(viewPager, 0);
  navigationTabBar.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onPageScrolled(final int position, final float positionOffset, final int positionOffsetPixels) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onPageSelected(final int position) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int state) {
      }
  });

  spaceNavigationView.initWithSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  spaceNavigationView.addSpaceItem(new SpaceItem(R.drawable.ic_bottom_call));
  spaceNavigationView.addSpaceItem(new SpaceItem(R.drawable.ic_bottom_happiness));
  spaceNavigationView.addSpaceItem(new SpaceItem(R.drawable.ic_bottom_call));
  spaceNavigationView.addSpaceItem(new SpaceItem(R.drawable.ic_bottom_happiness));
  spaceNavigationView.setCentreButtonIconColorFilterEnabled(false);
  spaceNavigationView.setSpaceOnClickListener(new SpaceOnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCentreButtonClick() {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onCentreButtonClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

      @Override
      public void onItemClick(int itemIndex) {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onItemClick " + itemIndex, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

      @Override
      public void onItemReselected(int itemIndex) {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onItemReselected " + itemIndex, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
  });
  ```

What I have to do to avoid this conflict ? 
Thanks.

Comment: please post logcat error

Comment: There is no error occurs .. only onClickListener on SpaceNavigationView not firing properly .. but I monitored that it's initialised when I tried to debug.